# Can't Delete/Copy/Paste files or folders in Gnome

Tags: gnome, kali-linux, desktop-environment, nemo

I am running Kali Linux with Gnome 3.34.2.

I read that Gnome does not support desktop icons anymore, so I installed "desktop-icons" extension.

Icons appear on the desktop but I can't copy, paste, delete, create folders, or remove them from the desktop. 
I have to go to the Desktop folder in Nemo file manager to perform those operations or use terminal.

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no fix because it is not a bug. Gnome 3 has a lot of annoying things like that but they are there by design. If you need a classic desktop environment, then I suggest something like XFCE

> Run `apt update && apt install kali-desktop-xfce` in a terminal session
>   to install the new Kali Linux Xfce environment. When asked to select
>   the “Default display manager”, choose lightdm.

More information [here](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/xfce-faq/).